# Gnuplot PDF Terminal Exhibits Font Issues on Mac

Tags: macos, gnuplot, homebrew, pango

Out of the blue, my Gnuplot has started having issues with the `pdfcairo` terminal.  The font in the produced PDF files is jammed as if the width of the individual characters was set to zero.  I am using Gnuplot 5.2.7 on Mac OS, installed via homebrew.

Here, a minimal not-working example:

```
reset
set terminal pdfcairo
set output "mnwe.pdf"
set xlabel "Time t"
set ylabel "sin(t)"
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) with lines notitle
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

I suspect that the font issue occurred after a recent update to patchlevel 7.  Gnuplot 5.2.2 on my Ubuntu machine works as expected and produces the following output for the same Gnuplot script:

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be possible to revert to the previous Gnuplot version with homebrew.

<strike>I confirmed that the `epscairo` and `pngcairo` terminals work as expected on my Mac with Gnuplot 5.2.7, so the issue is solely with the `pdfcairo` terminal.</strike>
Edit: In fact, the bug does affect the other Cairo-based terminals as well.  Don't know what I did wrong when I checked first.

I would appreciate any pointers at how to fix this.

Comment: There is a similar report on the gnuplot issue tracker that implicates use of pango version 1.44 in the recent homebrew build of gnuplot 5.2.7.  https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2194/

Comment: FYI here is the issue on the pango git: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pango/issues/422

Comment: Thank you @bibi! This is still an issue in gnuplot 5.2.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Aug. 24, 2020, the version of Pango on homebrew is 1.46.1 and this bug seems to have been fixed. Doing a clean installation of Gnuplot and Pango via homebrew should solve this problem.

Answer (score 17):

For Homebrew, I changed the pango formula to stick to version 1.43

Until it gets fixed, this should solve the problem:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies pango
brew install iltommi/brews/pango
```

This will install this formula: https://github.com/iltommi/homebrew-brews/blob/master/pango.rb in which I replaced the v1.44 to 1.43

Comment: Excellent. I confirmed that this works as a workaround for now.

Comment: I have to repeat this process every time another Homebrew formula wants to update pango

Comment: One-line replacement for `brew upgrade`:  
`brew uninstall pango && brew upgrade && brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies pango && brew install iltommi/brews/pango`

Answer (score 1):

Installing newer version **Pango 1.45.5** seems to resolves the issue as well, please confirm:

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies pango
brew install dersimn/craft/pango
```

Formula: https://github.com/dersimn/homebrew-craft/blob/master/Formula/pango.rb