# Displaying font for a gnuplot terminal

Tags: macos, gnuplot

In `qt` terminal, `show term` says:

`terminal type is qt 0 font "Sans,9"`

but `cairo` terminals never mention anything about fonts:

`terminal type is pdfcairo  transparent enhanced fontscale 0.5 size 5.00in, 3.00in`

Manual does not really help by refering to the freedesktop website which provides zero useful information to solve the problem. So how do I find what font is `gnuplot` (or its associates) trying to use (and failing miserably) on OSX.

My goal is to figure out what happened on my system. After plotting with instructions that said to use `Helvetica`, I keep getting plots with damaged text such as this:
[image]

This only happens with `cairo` type terminals and only since I tried to plot with Helvetica settings, which is probably not on my system. I tried regenerating font cach on OSX by `fc-cache -fv` with no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely the known OSX pango/cairo bug (version 1.44 is bad, version 1.43 is good). The reported solution is to downgrade the pango library.

- [gnuplot Issue #2197](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2194/)
- [pango/harfbuzz font issues](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/2394#issuecomment-626254448)
- [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698204/gnuplot-pdf-terminal-exhibits-font-issues-on-mac)