# Overlapping letters in tics and labels gnuplot 5.4

Tags: gnuplot, axis-labels

I have recently updated my gnuplot to the latest 5.4. I find problems with the labels and tics using the pngcairo terminal. For example, taking a simplified example from the official website

```
set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "arial,20" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'pm3d6.png'
set pm3d map
splot sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))/sqrt(x**2+y**2)
```

I get a figure that looks fine, but letters in the labels and tics overlap in a strange way. Any idea about why this happens?

[image: Gnuplot output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely a known bug in the pango/cairo libraries.  The only solution I have seen is to downgrade to a working version of libpango (1.43 rather than 1.44).
See

[Gnuplot PDF Terminal Exhibits Font Issues on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698204)

https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2194/

https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/2394#issuecomment-626254448